# error: extraneous argument label 'no1:' in call

Tags: swift

Consider the code given below

```
class division {
    var count: Int = 0
    func incrementBy(no1: Int, no2: Int) {
        count = no1 / no2
        println(count)
    }
}

let counter = division()
counter.incrementBy(no1:1800, no2: 3)
```

It gives following error :

```
error: extraneous argument label 'no1:' in call
counter.incrementBy(no1:1800, no2: 3)
                   ^~~~~
```

When I remove the label `no1`, compiler doesn't complain for the label `no2`.

When I remove both levels `no1` and `no2`, it gives following error :

```
error: missing argument label 'no2:' in call
counter.incrementBy(1800,  3)
                   ^
                           no2:
```

Can anyone please explain this behaviour. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your Swift version? After removing no1 its working for me.

Comment: @Md.Muzahidul After removing no1, its also working for me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## *Swift 3*

The contents of this answer (written for Swift 2.2 bbelow) is all mostly still applicable, but with the difference that the following default behavior now holds in Swift 3:

- **All** the function parameters have the same external parameter name as the internal one, unless otherwise specified.

I.e., the first function parameter no longer has an empty (omitted, `_`) external parameter name, per default, as was the case in Swift 2.2.

For additional details, see the following accepted and implemented Swift Evolution proposal:

- [SE-0046: Establish consistent label behavior across all parameters including first labels](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0046-first-label.md)

---

## *Swift 2*

#### Functions: external and internal parameter names

For any function in Swift, the function parameters has *internal* as well as *external* parameter names. By default, the following default behaviour holds:

- The first function parameter has an empty (omitted, `_`) external parameter name.
- All the following parameters have the same external parameter name as the internal one, unless otherwise specified.

Hence, following function

```
func foo(first: Int, second: Int) {}
```

is called as

```
foo(1, second: 2)
//  |     \
//  |   by default, same external as internal parameter name
//   \
//    by default, no external parameter name
```

Now, you can naturally specify whether also the first function parameter should have an external name (which then needs to be specified when calling the function):

```
func foo(firstExternal first: Int, second: Int) {}

// called as
foo(firstExternal: 1, second: 2)
```

Likewise, you may specify that you want the second parameter to have no external name (omitted) by specifying the external name as an underscore `_`.

```
func foo(first: Int, _ second: Int) {}

// called as
foo(1, 2)
```

If we return to the first example above (default behaviour), we realize that if we specify no external names, e.g.

```
func foo(first: Int, second: Int) {}
```

we get a "default" function signature (w.r.t. external parameter names) that is the equivalence of the following explicitly stated external names:

```
func foo(_ first: Int, second second: Int) {}
//       |               \
//       |       same external as internal parameter name
//        \
//    no (omitted) external parameter name
```

For additional details, see

- [The Language Guide - Functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html)

### Your specific example

Using the knowledge from above, we can apply it to your specific example, looking only at the signature of your function `incrementBy`:

```
func incrementBy(no1: Int, no2: Int) { ... }
//               |          \
//               |    no explicitly stated external names: hence, since
//               |    this is not the first parameter, the external name
//               |    is set to the same as the internal name (no2), by default
//                \
//       no explicitly stated external names: hence, since this is the
//       first parameter, the external name is omitted, by default
```

Hence, we call your function `incrementBy` as

```
incrementBy(1, no2: 2)
```

With this, we also realize why your two own attempts---included in your question---yields errors:

> **Error #1**
>
> ```
> error: extraneous argument label 'no1:' in call
> counter.incrementBy(no1:1800, no2: 3)
> ```
>
> As explained by this error message, you have an extraneous argument
>   label for the first function argument: as covered above, the first
>   function parameter has an omitted external parameter name by default
>   (which is in effect in your example), and hence, when calling it, 
>   we should include no argument label for the first parameter.
>
> **Error #2**
>
> ```
> error: missing argument label 'no2:' in call
> counter.incrementBy(1800,  3)
> ```
>
> This attempted call, on the other hand, correctly omits external
>   parameter name label for the first argument, but does so also for the
>   second argument. The second function parameter of `incrementBy`,
>   however, has the same external parameter name as its internal one, and
>   hence, the external parameter name label `no2:` must be included in
>   the call to the function.

Comment: Above explanation is valid for methods and not for functions.

Comment: @JayramKumar the above holds for methods as well as (global) functions. The only thing I haven't mentioned is initializers, for which all initializer parameters have, by default, the same external as internal parameter name (i.e. first parameter does not have an omitted (`_`) external name by default).

Comment: `func foo(a:Int, b:Int) -> Int {
    return a + b
}
println(foo(2,b:3)); //error: extraneous argument label 'b:' in call`, I am using swift 1.2

Comment: @JayramKumar Swift 1.2 can almost be considered ancient, you should consider updating to a less old and premature version of Swift. Current Xcode 7.3 ships with Swift 2.2.

Comment: great answer but stupid syntax design

Comment: @martynmlostekk Thanks. I can agree that the syntax is, if not stupid, at least a bit inconsistent (first parameter vs rest), leading to confusion for many new Swift developers. Swift 3, however, will remedy this inconsistency whereafter external/internal parameter rules for functions will be consistent for all parameters, and hence consistent with the current rules for parameters in initializers. See [this accepted evolution proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0046-first-label.md).

Comment: oooh.. thats great news! thanks for sharing it!